# Formatar @Html.Label - MVC

Tags: html5, css3, asp.net-mvc-5

Em minha pagina eu tenho um:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Bem Vindo(a) " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", actionName: "Index", controllerName: "RelatorioTagModels1")
```

Que gera, o "Bem vindo" da pagina abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem, eu nao quero que fique como link, queria somente um `Label`, então troquei o codigo para:

```
@Html.Label("Bem Vindo(a) " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!");
```

Porem, não consigo formatar, deixar igual a pagina anterior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta certo usar `@Html.Label`? para isso?
Como devo formatar para deixar visualmente igual ao `@Html.ActionLink`?

Comment: Boa noite meu caro, está formação pode ser feita no CSS?

Comment: @Anselmo sim, estou trabalhando com CSS, mas ja tentei achar essa configuração do `ActionLink` para mudar para o `Label` mas sem sucesso

Comment: Posso estar errado mas certamente deve ter uma classe ou ID que formata o action.link, procura e altera para .label

Comment: Por padrão o mvc utiliza o bootstrap. No css do boostrap deve ter algo como: navbar > a e então o efeito de manter a posição ali no meio... Quando vc altera para label ele perde. Inspeciona o elemento quando tiver com o link e verifica qual a classe que está ativa no css, e cria uma classe pra vc utilizando a label.

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel inspeciona a página html gerada pelo `ActionLink` e note quais classes css são incluídas no elemento, depois veja na documentação do método `.Label()` como passar uma classe css adicional para ser incluida no elemento e coloque as classes anteriormente notadas no ActionLink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que seu CSS tem algo que formata essa linha baseado na tag `<a>` do HTML [Link sobre CSS Aninhado](http://www.htmlprogressivo.net/2014/01/Seletores-descendentes-Tutorial-CSS.html)

Exemplo:

```
.Topo{}
.Topo a { aqui está o codigo que alinha e deixa branco}
```

Então quando vc colocou sem o `<a href` ele ficou sem a formatação. (não chegou a nem ser chamado o css aninhado)

**3 sugestões:**

---

**1. Desabilite o CSS para `<A>` e mude para algo personalizado**
Ex:

```
.Topo a {}
```

vc irá substituir por:

```
.MinhaClass{ mesmo código do de cima}
```

e você chamará assim:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Bem Vindo(a) " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", actionName: "Index", controllerName: "RelatorioTagModels1", new with {.class = "MinhaClass" })
```

*OBS: Para você encontrar qual é a classe utilize o 'inspecionar' do seu navegador, ele mostrará qual css é.

---

**2. Deixe com `<a>` mas desabilite o click**

Crie o seguinte css:

```
.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

ai basta vc chamar esse disable:

@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Bem Vindo(a) " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", actionName: "Index", controllerName: "RelatorioTagModels1", new with {.class = "disabled" })

---

**3. Crie um style que corrija o label**
algo como:

```
.LabelNome{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
}
```

e ai você chama esse LabelNome igual aos exemplos acima

```
new with {.class = "LabelNome"
```

*OBS: Poderá ser necessário, mudar o valor 20px*